# Is there a way to have Jedis automatically use a connection pool for command methods?

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I came across a class in a project I'm working on that looks like

```java
public class RedisClient {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisClient.class);
    JedisPool pool;
    public RedisClient(String redisHost, int redisPort, String redisPassword) {
        JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = buildPoolConfig();
        try {
            pool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, redisHost, redisPort, 10000, redisPassword, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("There's been an error while Jedis attempted to retrieve a thread from the pool", e);
        }
    }
    public void set(String key, String value) {
        try (Jedis jedis = pool.getResource()) {
            jedis.set(key, value);
        }
    }
   // ... a few more command methods wrapped with try (Jedis jedis = pool.getResource())
   // like get, expire, etc.
```

While this isn't a bad approach by any means (pretty standard adapter pattern to my eyes), I'm wondering if Jedis either takes care of this automatically (coming from Python, I was hoping it maybe hid this detail a la [`redis`](https://pypi.org/project/redis/#connection-pools), or there was another way to configure an existing client to "use a connection pool for each command". I see that `jedis.Jedis` has a [setDataSource](https://github.com/redis/jedis/blob/b53f03290c10d02f8895f589b12915b002f5f258/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/Jedis.java#L3927) method that accepts a `JedisPool`, but I'm having trouble determining what that actually does and if it helps me answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

JedisPool is implemented on top of `commons-pool2`. According to the design of commons-pool2, you can borrow an object but you'd have to return that object after using it. Jedis incorporates `close` method in this returning process to ease users' works with the help of Java's try-with-resources feature. `setDataSource` method is used in the borrowing process, similar to close method being used in returning process.

Last but not least, a user must not use `setDataSource` method; unless s/he is implementing her own version of JedisPool.